# angular-datatables - Can a column's renderWith function return value from a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, datatables

Is it possible to make a call to a service/filter that returns a promise from within a column's renderWith() function? I'm attempting to do that and the output is always "[object Object]".

```
vm.dtInstance = {};

vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(MyService.getData())
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withOption('rowCallback', casesDtRowCallback)
            .withBootstrap()
            .withOption('createdRow', createdRow)
            .withOption('scrollX', true)
            .withOption('scrollY', false);

vm.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null)
                .withTitle('ID')
                .renderWith(idHtml),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null)
                .withTitle('Status')
                .renderWith(statusHtml),
];

function caseStatusHtml(data, type, full, meta) {
            return $filter('myCustomFilter')(data.theStatus).then(function(response) {
                // myCustomFilter returns a string
                return response;
            })
}
```

Comment: [This question](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/22) appears to be at least similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ff:

```
function caseStatusHtml(data, type, full, meta) {
    $filter('myCustomFilter')(data.theStatus).then(function(response) {
        $(meta.settings.aoData[meta.row].anCells[meta.col]).text(response);
    });
    return data;
}
```